# Composite Source with WMQ Node in Mule ESB

Tags: mule

By using composite source in Mule ESB, it is possible to get input from different queue at a time. Is there any method to get to know the input WMQ node name.e.g.

I have 2 queue (ABC & XYZ) from which input can be obtained and further transformation can be applied. Is there any possible way to get to know the queue name from which the message received.

Comment: Soon after the queue, Keep logger and check #[message.inboundProperties] and #[message.outboundProperties] . You can able to see all the properties and whatever the value (Queue name or anything) can be extracted based on your need basis.

Comment: #[message.inboundProperties.MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT]  helps me to get the queue name if i use logger node. But I want to use this queue name in one java transformer node which is followed by WMQ Node. message.getInboundPropertyNames() gives only properties but not the values of the properties

Comment: message.getInboundProperty("MULE_ORIGINATING_ENDPOINT")  wouldn't this give you the value of the property you are looking for ?

Comment: yes, It is working. Thanks. I was trying the same without inverted Commas  " " inside the bracket . That's why getting error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use composite-source if you need to behave differently based of the queue name.

What I would recomend is to design your flows acordingly to your needs:

```
flow(queueA)->flowVars.queueName="queueA"->flow-ref(realwork)
flow(queueB)->flowVars.queueName="queueB"->flow-ref(realwork)
flow(realwork)->dotherealworkhere
```